# How to filter query with multiple condition in URL - OData

Tags: development, .net, c-sharp

I want to filter the data with Type 'Com and State 'Disconnected'. With below code i am getting the exception. How do I fix this?
Please help!

```
$filter=(contains(Type,'Com') and contains(State,'Disconnected'))
```

Comment: Are you using SharePoint REST APIs? What's is the exception / error message? I don't think contains operator is supported in SharePoint REST APIs.

Answer (score 0):

Use `substringof` instead of `contains`. When using `substringof`, the first parameter is the string to search for and the second parameter is the name of the field/column to search.

```
$filter=(substringof('Com',Type) and substringof('Disconnected',State))
```

For more information see [OData query operators supported in the SharePoint REST service](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/use-odata-query-operations-in-sharepoint-rest-requests#odata-query-operators-supported-in-the-sharepoint-rest-service?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-9698).

[image: Supported OData query options]